# CryptoJS encrypt in aes-256-cbc returns an unexpected value

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I am encrypting some data using [CryptoJS](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) and comparing it to [an online tool](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption) and I am not getting the same result. In fact the result from CryptoJS in not decryptable with the tool.

I am trying to encrypt in AES-256-CBC with the following parameters:

```
text = '111222333'
iv = 'I8zyA4lVhMCaJ5Kg'
key = '6fa979f20126cb08aa645a8f495f6d85'
```

Here's my code:

```
let text = '111222333';

aesEncrypt(data) {
    let key = '6fa979f20126cb08aa645a8f495f6d85';    //length 32
    let iv = 'I8zyA4lVhMCaJ5Kg';                     //length 16
    let cipher = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key, {
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
    return cipher.toString();
}

aesEncrypt(text);
```

The resulting encrypted string is `U2FsdGVkX1+f3UywYmIdtb50bzdxASRCSqB00OijOb0=` while the one obtained with the online tool is `B6AeMHPHkEe7/KHsZ6TW/Q==`. Why are they different, I seem to be using the same parameters?

My plan in using CryptoJS is to encrypt some data client side and then be able to decrypt it server side, if needed. But the differences in both encrypted values is stopping me to do so.

Comment: maybe the delta is in the padding?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How 'bout encoding your data as UTF-8. Just like the "online tool" is doing.

Use [`CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse`](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders)  to achieve what I'm saying.

```js
aesEncrypt (data) {
   const key = '6fa979f20126cb08aa645a8f495f6d85'
   const iv = 'I8zyA4lVhMCaJ5Kg'
   
   const cipher = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), {
       iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv), // parse the IV 
       padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
       mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
   })
   
   // e.g. B6AeMHPHkEe7/KHsZ6TW/Q==
   return cipher.toString()
}
```

Code snippet using CryptoJS.

```js
function aesEncrypt (data) {
   const key = '6fa979f20126cb08aa645a8f495f6d85'
   const iv = 'I8zyA4lVhMCaJ5Kg'
   const cipher = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), {
       iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv),
       padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
       mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
   })

   return cipher.toString()
}

// e.g. B6AeMHPHkEe7/KHsZ6TW/Q==
console.log(aesEncrypt('111222333'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
```

[Working Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-srpjrz)

Comment: That definitely solved the problem, thank you. Do you have any idea how the key and iv are handled if the UTF8.parse is not specified?

Comment: UTF8 parsing is specified in every language. They are handled according to the encoding your text editor is using (or how you encoded). UTF8 is a standard one so this can be used in java or anywhere else and you'll get the same result. @AlexBlais

Comment: I meant, CryptoJS doesn't seem to default to UTF8 since it has to be specified. My guess would have been it defaulted to base64 or something like that. Is that correct?

Comment: @AlexBlais no it's your text editor and you can't expect a library to assume an encoding. It seriously affects the encryption. You just saw :')

Comment: How to do decrypt?

Comment: @NitinKarale there's an example for decryption in the ciphers section of the [link I have linked in the answer body](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#ciphers)

Answer (score 1):

Based on WeeGee's answer, added this function aesDecrypt in order to decrypt back the encrypted text and return the string in UTF8.  @WeeGee you saved my day.

```
const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('6fa979f20126cb08aa645a8f495f6d85');
const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('I8zyA4lVhMCaJ5Kg');

const text = '111222333';

function aesEncrypt(data) {
    let cipher = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key, {
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
    return cipher.toString();
}

function aesDecrypt(data) {
  let cipher = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, key, {
      iv: iv,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
  });
  return cipher.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}

const encryptedText = aesEncrypt(text);
const decryptedText = aesDecrypt(encryptedText);

console.log('Before Encrypt - ' + text);
console.log('Encrypted Text - ' + encryptedText);
console.log('Decrypted Text - ' + decryptedText);
```

Output

```
Before Encrypt - 111222333 
Encrypted Text - B6AeMHPHkEe7/KHsZ6TW/Q==
Decrypted Text - 111222333
```